# Blender 3D Texture over material

Tags: textures, blender

Hello i am facing a problem setting a texture as complete part of the object. I have 3 different materials on one object each has a unique color, but now i want to overlay a texture over the whole body of the object.
Its kind of working but not as expected.

Here is the current state:
[texturedImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdcrT.jpg)

[optionsOnBlender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgXQ5.png)

The original view is like this where you can see the different materials attached to the proper fields.

[originalStructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFdby.jpg)

As you can see here the strucure should not be broken i only want to overlay the texture over the whole body. Here you can see that the image is constantly repeating but even if i change the marked option in red to "extend" it gets weired behaviour.

[setTexture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGqGZ.jpg)

Now when i go to Uv-Editing i clearly can see that the strucutre is not adjusted to the size  so i will adjust it manually.
[uv-editing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mS2wI.png)

Adjusted the size:
[adjustedSize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gEBW.jpg)

Now after that i go back to layout and can see that the texture just goes weirdly over the object fields but how to overlay it completely.

[endResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g24eN.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I finally made it with a very simple trick. After setting the texture navigate to the UV-editing panel und select all and hit "U" and select "Cube projection". This leads to extending texture like on a cube to a whole side.
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJlw1.jpg)